# How many Umras and Hajj were done by the Prophet (SAW)?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, hajj, umrah

How many Umras and Hajj were done by the Prophet(PBUH) in his lifetime?

Please refer the year, and the age of the Prophet(SAW) at that time, and add some reference from hadiths

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ الْمُثَنَّى، حَدَّثَنِي عَبْدُ الصَّمَدِ،
>   حَدَّثَنَا هَمَّامٌ، حَدَّثَنَا قَتَادَةُ، قَالَ سَأَلْتُ أَنَسًا كَمْ
>   حَجَّ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ حَجَّةً وَاحِدَةً
>   وَاعْتَمَرَ أَرْبَعَ عُمَرٍ ‏.‏ ثُمَّ ذَكَرَ بِمِثْلِ حَدِيثِ هَدَّابٍ
>   ‏.‏
>
> I asked Anas (Allah be pleased with him) as to how many Pilgrimages
>   had been performed by Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him), and
>   he replied: One Hajj and four 'Umras were performed by him.
>   [Sahih Muslim 1253 ]

The rest of the hadith is the same.

> قُلْتُ لأَنَسِ بْنِ مَالِكٍ كَمْ حَجَّ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم
>   قَالَ حَجَّةٌ وَاحِدَةٌ وَاعْتَمَرَ أَرْبَعَ عُمَرٍ عُمْرَةٌ فِي ذِي
>   الْقَعْدَةِ وَعُمْرَةُ الْحُدَيْبِيَةِ وَعُمْرَةٌ مَعَ حَجَّتِهِ
>   وَعُمْرَةُ الْجِعِرَّانَةِ إِذْ قَسَّمَ غَنِيمَةَ حُنَيْنٍ ‏.‏
>
> said to Anas bin Malik: 'How many times did the Prophet perform Hajj?' He
>   said: 'He performed one Hajj and he performed four Umrah: An Umrah
>   during Dhul-Qa'dah; the Umrah of Al-Hudaibiyah, and Umrah with his
>   Hajj, and an Umrah from Al-Ji'irranah when he divided up the war
>   spoils of Hunain.'" 
>   [Jami` at-Tirmidhi 821 (Sahih)]

So 4 Umras and only one Hajj:

1. Umrah Hudaybiyah or the time Hudaybiyah in Dhi Qa'da "ذي القعدة".
2. Umrah next year in Dhi Qa'da.
3. Umrah of Jarana, where the spoils Hunain Division in Dhi Qa'da in
   the eighth year
4. The fourth Umrah that is performed by the Prophet with the Wadda' (Farewell)
   Pilgrimage "حجة الوداع" in the tenth year of Hijri.

Answer (score 2):

It has been recorded that the Messenger of Allah (saws) performed a total of four Umrahs and one Hajj pilgrimage.

Umrah 1: 6th Hijri, after the Treaty of Hudaibiya. Although he was not allowed to visit the Kaaba by the polytheists of Makkah to perform Umrah, it is still counted as an Umrah. He came out of the Ehram, shaved his head, and sacrificed his hadi (animal) and went back to Medina. The deal made with the polytheists, that he would return to Medina, and come back the next year for his Umrah.

Umrah 2: 7th Hijri, as per the Treaty of Hudaibiyah.

Umrah 3. 8th Hijri, after returning from the Battle of Hunain.

Umrah 4: 10th Hijri, along with the Hajj.

Comment: 1+ because even if your answer lacks references, it gives information i missed in others!